# Taylor polynomial of $\frac{1}{1-x-y}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I need to calculate the 2nd order Taylor polynomial at the origin of 
$$f(x,y) = {1 \over{1-x-y}}$$

I have looked at two ways, and not sure which is simpler. We can split it by partial derivatives and brute force the definition, or use the expansion of $1\over 1-t$.

Much help is appreciated.

Comment: Your second approach is by far the most efficient.